# Broadcast Receiver for Application Purchase/Installation

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, google-play

I have an application with a broadcast receiver, and I'm trying to figure out how to receive the broadcast of when an app from the Market is purchased and/or installed. Is this possible?

I've tried setting a receiver for `android.Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of receiving a broadcast intent on purchase/install of the application.  From what I recall reading about this in the past, is that it's a security concern.

From the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED), it even states that a new application won't receive the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast intent.  PURCHASE_STATE is also irrelevant since the app isn't installed yet at purchase time.

Comment: Thank you. I would actually like to have another application detect when an app is installed, not detect when the app itself is installed if I am making myself clear. So would I be able to install the app I want to detect/receive the broadcast and then have it run code once it receives the broadcast for purchase state or package added from another app installation?